# Yarn using error: how to use yarn on git bash

Tags: node.js, bash, yarnpkg

After installed the yarn dependency management by npm , and I have got the success info on cmd version 0.21.3.
When I turn on the git bash to use yarn command, failed with those errors:

```
  module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\c\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `npm link` command to create the symlink to your `yarn` module. You can use the below command.

```
npm link yarn
```

After that try executing the `yarn` command in your git bash.

Hope this helps!